# For what values of $\gamma > 0$ does $n^{\gamma} (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)^2$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is not for homework, but I would please just like a hint.  The question asks

> For what values of $\gamma > 0$ does $n^{\gamma} (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)^2$ converge?

I did a couple of tests, and believe that $n^{\gamma} (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)^2 \to 0$ for $0 < \gamma < 2$, and $n^{\gamma} (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)^2 \to \infty$ for $\gamma \geq 2$.  I've been working on the second claim a bit, but haven't made any real progress.  If I can show that $n^2 (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)^2 \to \infty$ then I would be done with the second claim.  The sequence $n^2 (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)^2$ grows very slowly, so maybe I can get an easier lower bound for $exp(n^2 (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)^2)$?  Any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** :

$$
n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1=
\exp(\frac{\log(n)}{n})-1=
(\frac{\log(n)}{n})+O((\frac{\log(n)}{n})^2) ...
$$

Comment: Do you need the Big O for the second term instead of little o?

Comment: @Jack corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

***$$n(\sqrt[n] n-1)=\frac {n(\sqrt[n] n-1)(\sqrt[n] n+1)}{(\sqrt[n] n+1)}=\frac {n^{ (n+2)/n}-n}{n^{ 1/n}+1}\to \infty$$***